# Setting and Retrieving the x:Name attribute for a XAML object

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider this WPF3D XAML snippet, bearing in mind that the object declared does *not* inherit `FrameworkElement`:

```
<Visual3D x:Name="SomeName" />
```

How, in code, would one go about *retrieving* the string specified for the value of `x:Name`? Yes, it's declared as a symbol for code-behind access at build time, but if you're transforming a logical tree with a non-`FrameworkElement` root into a different format, there's no `FrameworkElement.NameProperty.GetValue()` defined.

Comment: No; this is a question about the behavior and features of WPF's XAML implementation, below the level of development patterns.

Comment: is traversing the visual tree to get this element by type a possibility ?

Comment: No; we're "transforming a logical tree with a non-FrameworkElement root". Walking the visual tree isn't possible because the XAML elements are not FrameworkElements.

Comment: Can you provide a larger snippet of the code? Is `Visual3D` contained within a `Viewport3D`?

Comment: It would distract from the question, which asks how to get the x:Name value from the object. It could be a non-FrameworkElement object which is not `Visual3D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class which inherit from the Visual 3D class and add the RuntimeNameProperty attribute on the class as well as a property which will be used to save the name.

Comment: I could, and it's one of the discussion points which prompted this question. But the class might be `sealed` or I won't have the ability to define an attached property. The advantage of `x:Name` is its canonical nature; every XAML element can take an `x:Name`.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to retrieve directly the x:Name property (that's the way how FrameworkElement fill in the Name property)